# R scrape multiple png files

Tags: r, web-scraping, png

I have tried to look at other subjects but it does not looks they are pertinent to my question. I am trying to scrape multiple .png plots with R from the 'Indicator' section of https://tradingeconomics.com/
For any indicator, there are multiple countries data and each country page includes a plot. I would like to find a way to scrape png files for each country through a single routine.
I have tried the first indicator ('growth rate') and yet my code is the following:

```
   library(stringr)
   library(dplyr)
   library(rvest) 

   tradeec <- read_html("https://tradingeconomics.com/country-list/gdp-growth-rate")
   tradeec_countries <- tradeec %>% html_nodes("td:nth-child(1)") %>%
   html_text()
   tradeec_countries <- str_replace_all(tradeec_countries, "[\r\n]" , "")
   tradeec_countries <- as.data.frame(tradeec_countries)
   tradeec_countries <- tradeec_countries[-c(91:95), ]

   tradeec_plots <- paste0("https://d3fy651gv2fhd3.cloudfront.net/charts", tradeec_countries, "-gdp-growth.png?s=", i)
```

Nonetheless I am not reaching my goal.
Any hint?

Answer (score 1):

### updated answer

For example, all the figures in **world** column of [link](https://tradingeconomics.com/country-list/gdp-growth-rate) can be obtained using the following code. Other columns, such as **Europe, America, Asia, Australia, G20** can also be obtained similarly.

```
page <- read_html("https://tradingeconomics.com/country-list/gdp-growth-rate")
url_init <- "https://tradingeconomics.com"
country_list <- html_nodes(page,"td a") %>% html_attr("href")
world_list <- paste(url_init,country_list,sep = "")

page_list <- vector(mode = "list")

for(page_index in 1:length(world_list)) {
    page_list[[page_index]] = read_html(world_list[page_index])
}

for (i in 1:length(page_list)) {
  figure_link <- html_nodes(page_list[[i]],"#ImageChart") %>% html_attr("src")
  figure_name <- gsub(".*charts/(.*png).*","\\1",figure_link,perl = TRUE)
  figure_name <- paste(i,"_",figure_name)
  download.file(figure_link,figure_name)
}
```

### original answer

The following code can get the figure's link and name.

```
tradeec <- read_html("https://tradingeconomics.com/south-africa/gdp-growth")
figure_link <- html_nodes(tradeec, "#ImageChart") %>% html_attr("src")
figure_name <- gsub(".*charts/(.*png).*", "\\1", figure_link, perl = T)
download.file(figure_link,figure_name)
```

Then you can replace **south-africa** in the link to a series of countries you wanted.

Comment: Thanks a loto for the hint. It works perfectly indeed. I am trying to find out a way to scrape all the countries' plots in a single routine, though. Do you think it is feasable?

Comment: The new one is great, thank you very much. I could not figure out how to write the double for loop. I am going to study it, now. Thanks again!

Comment: I am happy that can help you.